# My DetailViewController isn't recognizing the '-configureView'

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, view, ios4

I had a problem with the splitView so I decided to make my own version of it using a ViewBasedApplication.  The view is set up to be like a splitView, but instead of having the static table when you flip it to landscape it will have the popover control like it normally does in the portrait mode.

I have everything set up, but I'm encountering an error when I select an item from the popover table. It isn't updating the view to go to the appropriate page that was selected in the table...the code for the setDetailItem in the ViewController.m file looks like this:

```
-(void)setDetailTime:(id)newDetailItem{
if(detailitem != newDetailItem) {
[detailitem release];
detailItem = [newDetailItem retain[;

[self configureView];

...
```

}

The problem is in the [sef configureView] line.  it says that "PDFViewController" may not respond to '-configureView'.  Im assuming this is because '-configureView' is specific to only the SplitView.  Any ideas of a way to workaround this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the backwards bracket in line 4 is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `PDFViewController` does not have a `configureView` method, which is why you're getting the warning (and why you're not seeing anything happen).

You probably need to instead call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` which basically tells the view to redraw itself.  I don't know if this will work for you, because I don't know how the rest of your class is written.